# in jQuery EasyUI when loading a datagrid, how can i get the total number returned before pagination

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui, jquery-pagination

I'm trying to get the total rows returned in  jQuery EasyUI datagrid when pagination enabled.
For example, if my query returns 143 rows but my datagrid has pagination enabled and pageSize set to 10.  How can i get the value of 143.  I need to know the total rows return before pagination.
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the total number of results as:

$('#datagrid_id').datagrid('getData').total